# Вопрос по ООП. Python 3. Crypto

Tags: python

Добрался до своих первых более менее серьезных проектов.
Функции не выкладываю, так как принцип простой. Купи на одной бирже, продай на другой. Интересует практика построения, для дальнейшего развития бота.

1. Где мера качества кода? Как ее понять?
2. Правильно ли выбрана конструкция и можно ли так, если работает?
3. Как запускать функции без while? Или так и нужно для непрерывной работы?
4. Какой пакет знаний необходим, чтобы сделать данный процесс асинхронным?
   Например, в данном случае, действия поступательные. Бот не будет продавать, пока не купит. Так и нужно. Но это, не более чем совпадение.
5. Нужно ли использовать здесь class? Если да, то зачем?
6. Какие решения могут быть лучше? Читал где-то, что `time.sleep` лучше не использовать. Почему, так и не понял.
   Много критики и все замечания. Спасибо за фидбек.

Идущему покоряется дорога (с)

**Код:**

```
'''Баланс валюты'''
def wallet_response():

'''Покупка валюты'''
def buy():

'''Продажа валюты на другой бирже'''
def sell():



while True:
    try:
        wallet_response()
        time.sleep(2)       
        buy()
        time.sleep(2)
        sell()
    except:
        print('Connection lost. Retry.')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

4. `Например, в данном случае, действия поступательные. Бот не будет продавать, пока не купит. Так и нужно. Но это, не более чем совпадение.`
   Все будет работать до тех пор пока не зальешь проект на хост. Когда запрос будут делать допустим 2 человека, то твоя программа сначала обслужит 1 человека, а затем 2. А если будет 1000 человек? Люди вряд-ли будут столько ждать.
5. В данном случае класс можно не использовать.
6. `time.sleep` останавливает твою программу на 2 секунды, и если тебе за это время надо будет выполнить какое-то другое действие, то оно не выполнится, т.к. программа будет остановлена на `x` промежуток времени.

Comment: 4. Спасибо за информацию! Понял. А что в таком случае делать? Программа для меня только, но вопрос интересный. Мало ли, заказик перепадет. Я бы разобрался.

Comment: 6. То есть, это сугубо вопрос эффективности?

Comment: Надо в таких случаях использовать асинхронное программирование, но к сожалению с на практике с этим я не так силен( сам разбираюсь.
Почитайте про модуль asyncio, с помощью него работают с асинхронностью.